# Common base class or interface for StackPanel and Control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, controls, stackpanel, base-class

I need a function to return something that can either be System.Windows.Controls.Control or System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.

Ideally it should be an interface thats implemented by both or a baseclass of both of them (I hate using object for this purpose)

The likes of UIElement etc seem to be exclusive to one of 'em only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) looks to be your only bet.

Answer (score 0):

FrameworkElement is the closest ancestor to both, but anything above that is fine (including UIElement):

```
System.Object 
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
    System.Windows.DependencyObject
      System.Windows.Media.Visual
        System.Windows.UIElement
          System.Windows.FrameworkElement
            System.Windows.Controls.Panel
              System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel

System.Object 
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
    System.Windows.DependencyObject
      System.Windows.Media.Visual
        System.Windows.UIElement
          System.Windows.FrameworkElement
            System.Windows.Controls.Control
```

Comment: thanks this works. i'd prefer Framework element as thats the closest ancestor and offers least probability of another developer using this for an unintended purpose.